# How do I pass parameters from an AngularJS component to a child Angular 2 component using ngDowngrade?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

The parent component (directive) written in AngularJS calls the child component as such.

```
    <div class="container">
        <preferences 
            prefix="user"
            permissions=options.permissions
            selected-permissions=user.permissions
            license=selectedLicense
            actions=true
            on-change=permissionsChangedCallback(selectedPermissions)>
        </preferences>
    </div>
</div>
```

The child, Preferences component is now written in Angular 2, and downgraded using

```
app.directive('preferences', downgradeComponent({component: PreferencesComponent}));
```

The function permissionsChangedCallback is defined in the parent Component's controller. 
Previously, the child component preferences used to call a function that checked whether on-change was supplied, and if it was, then the child will call it passing child-specific parameters:

```
// Previous AngularJS preferences child functions
    if (this.onChange) {
                this.onChange({
                    selectedPermissions: this.selectedPermissions
                });
            }
```

However, I can't figure out how to pass the on-change to the child now that's the child is written in angular 2.

This is what I've tried (didn't work):

```
<preferences
    [prefix]="'user'"
    [permissions]=options.permissions
    [selected-permissions]=user.permissions
    [license]=selectedLicense
    [actions]=true
    (change)="permissionsChangedCallback(selectedPermissions)"> <------ This one doesn't work, the child gets a string?
</preferences>
```

Comment: The js part of your app still uses js bindings for downgraded components. Function bindings should be converted to use output event emitters

Comment: How do I pass it from the parent component, and how do i call it from the child component?